# put view element on the 1st column of TableLayout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have a table layout, there are 3 rows in the table. In the 1st & 2nd row, each row has 3 `TextView` elements (i.e. 3 columns). The **last row** has only one `TextView`:

```
<TableLayout>
     <!--1st row-->
     <TableRow>
          <TextView        
              android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon1"
              android:text="@string/one" />

           <TextView        
              android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon2"
              android:text="@string/two" /> 

           <TextView        
              android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon3"
              android:text="@string/three" />
     </TableRow>     

     <!--2nd row-->
     <TableRow>
          <TextView        
              android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon4"
              android:text="@string/four" />

           <TextView        
              android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon5"
              android:text="@string/five" /> 

           <TextView        
              android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon6"
              android:text="@string/six" />
     </TableRow>   

     <!--3rd row-->
     <TableRow>
           <!--How to put it in the left side (1st column) only?-->
          <TextView        
              android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon7"
              android:text="@string/seven" />
     </TableRow>  
</TableLayout>
```

The 3rd row has only one `TextView` element, when run my app, it is located in the middle of the 3rd row, and if I set a `onClickeListener` on the `TextView`, user can click the whole row.

**Question 1:**

How to make the `TextView` on the 3rd row to be located on the left side of the row (i.e. the 1st column) and make only the cell clickable instead of the whole row?

**Question 2:**

What about if I have 2 `TextView` elements in the last row, I would like to have them in the 1st & 2nd column respectively, with empty 3rd column. How to achieve this then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Works for me :

```
<!--3rd row-->
    <TableRow>
      <!--How to put it in the left side (1st column) only?-->
      <TextView        
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:drawableTop="@drawable/creditcard"
          android:text="@string/app_name" />
      <TextView        
           android:layout_span="2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</TableRow>
```

2) Just do the same things with a empty `TextView`, without `android:layout_span="2"`

Answer (score 0):

put your textview outside the TableRow dont use tablerow for last row your problem will be solved

Comment: What about if I have 2 TextView elements in the last row, I would like to have them in the 1st & 2nd column respectively, with empty 3rd column. How to achieve this then? I still need TableRow right?